# ,class varchar(2) NOT NULL error code 1064

Tags: mysql

ERROR: 16:47:31

```
CREATE TABLE orders 
(order_id char(5) NOT NULL 
,part_id varchar(5) NOT NULL 
,order_date DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT TIMESTAMP 
,class varchar(5) NOT NULL 
,comments varchar(75) NOT NULL 
,part_description varchar(75) NOT NULL 
,customer_id varchar(5) NOT NULL 
,CONSTRAINT pk_orderPRIMARY PRIMARY KEY (order_id) 
,CONSTRAINT fk_customer_id FOREIGN KEY (customer_id) 
REFERENCES customer_id(customer_id))
```

Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ',class varchar(5) NOT NULL ,comments varchar(75) NOT NULL ,part_description varc' at line 5    0.000 sec

,class varchar(5) NOT NULL ,comments varchar(75) NOT NULL ,part_description

class varchar(5) NOT NULL ,comments varchar(75) NOT NULL ,part_description

MySQL is not running the code due to a varchar error, but the values are defined as "2" and NOT NULL, I do not understand. I expected smooth sailing from defining the varchar as text values, but I seemed to hit a log on the way. Please help!

Comment: Do you mean `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` instead of `TIMESTAMP` for the default of `order_date`?

Comment: I'd be sorely tempted to use integers for internal database references

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE `orders` (
 `order_id` char(5) NOT NULL, 
 `part_id` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
 `order_date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 `class` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
 `comments` varchar(75) NOT NULL,
 `part_description` varchar(75) NOT NULL,
 `customer_id` varchar(5) NOT NULL
)
```

Comment: Yes, I just changed the DATETIME to CURRENT TIME_STAMP and by adding NOT NULL I was able to input the date provided Thanks so much for responding! =^.^=